# NeuralProphet module gives an error while loading

Tags: python

I have python 3.7.6 environment and NeuralProphet 3.2. It was working fine until 2 weeks ago. Then I decided to upgrade to 5.2 version. I got an error with holidays library in NeuralProphet. Then, I decided to downgrade it to version 3.2. I got the same error. The details are here.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9717d38c3e86> in <module>
      2 import numpy as np
      3 from datetime import datetime
----> 4 from neuralprophet import NeuralProphet

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\neuralprophet\__init__.py in <module>
     23     warnings_log.addHandler(f_handler)
     24 
---> 25 from .forecaster import NeuralProphet
     26 from .utils import set_random_seed, set_log_level
     27 from .df_utils import split_df

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\neuralprophet\forecaster.py in <module>
      9 from tqdm import tqdm
     10 
---> 11 from neuralprophet import configure
     12 from neuralprophet import time_net
     13 from neuralprophet import time_dataset

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\neuralprophet\configure.py in <module>
     10 import types
     11 
---> 12 from neuralprophet import utils_torch, utils, df_utils
     13 
     14 log = logging.getLogger("NP.config")

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\neuralprophet\utils_torch.py in <module>
      6 from torch_lr_finder import LRFinder
      7 
----> 8 from neuralprophet import utils
      9 
     10 log = logging.getLogger("NP.utils_torch")

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\neuralprophet\utils.py in <module>
      6 import torch
      7 from collections import OrderedDict
----> 8 from neuralprophet import hdays as hdays_part2
      9 import holidays as pyholidays
     10 import warnings

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\neuralprophet\hdays.py in <module>
    431 
    432 
--> 433 class TU(Turkey):
    434     pass
    435 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\holidays\registry.py in __init__(self, path, *args, **kwargs)
    180         if args:
    181             raise TypeError(
--> 182                 "This is a python-holidays entity loader class. "
    183                 "For entity inheritance purposes please import a class you "
    184                 "want to derive from directly: e.g., "

TypeError: This is a python-holidays entity loader class. For entity inheritance purposes please import a class you want to derive from directly: e.g., `from holidays.countries import Entity` or `from holidays.financial import Entity`.
```

It seems to be an issue with holidays library. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I tried to run in a virtual environment by downloading only Neiralprophet version 3.2  and got the same error.

Comment: https://github.com/ourownstory/neural_prophet/issues/1363 suggestion is tu upgrade to python 3.8+ and use latest NeuralProphet